# XCode: Title in Interface builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

In the Interface build, I am trying to set the title for `NSTextField`. This text is static text. Now I want only a portion of text to be in **bold**. When I select the text and do a bold, the entire title becomes bold. It basically is like all or nothing. Is there a way I can bold only a portion of the text ?.

I am using `Xcode version 3.2.5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a custom class deriving from `NSValueTransformer`. In the `Interface Builder` you than can add the CustomValueTransformer to the `NSTextField`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you'll have to do that programmatically -- I couldn't find a way to style just part of the text in the field in Interface Builder.